# What would be the Zsh equivalent to : ${VAR:=value}

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh

In the traditional Bourne Shell (sh), if one wants to make sure that, at some point in the script, a variable has been set and at least it has some specific default value, one can use this construct:

```
: "${VAR:=defaultValue}"
```

What would be the equivalent for a Zsh script?

Thanks.

Edit: I mean, in case there is a Zsh specific way for doing this. Instead of just doing the true command (:).

Edit2: Rightfully quoting the parameter expansion. See Stéphane Chazelas' answer.

Comment: The `${parameter:=[word]}` syntax is [defined by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), is there any reason you don't want to use that?

Comment: Oh, no reason at all for not using ${var:=value}, I am fine with it. Just asking in case there is a Zsh-specific way for when all one wants to do is the paramenter expansion by itself (not as a side effect of executing a command). In sh one uses the ':' command for this. And it seems it is the same for zsh and the rest of shells (thanks @Stéphane Chazelas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually,

```
: ${VAR:=defaultValue}
```

is correct in `zsh` (provided you've not enabled the `globsubst` option), but not in other shells. In other Bourne-like shells, that would constitute a denial of service vulnerability unless you enable the `noglob` options as seen at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22565).

In those, you'd need

```
: "${VAR:=defaultValue}"
```

`zsh` does support those Bourne operators and even introduces a couple of its own in that same vein:

- `${VAR::=value}` unconditionally assigns `value` to the variable (and expand to the result). That is useful in `zsh` as it can be combined with other parameter expansion operator or flags.
- `${:-value}` (i.e. with `VAR` omitted) expands to `value`. Again useful when combined with other operators.

Another option here is to do:

```
VAR=${VAR:-defaultValue}
```

Which would be OK in zsh and all other Bourne-like shells and may convey the meaning more clearly.

Comment: Thank you for the link "Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells". Very, VERY, enlightening.